# Reading columns from excel file using linq

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, excel, linq-to-excel

I am reading an excel file but not all the files have the same column headers but the column order are always the same. I want to read the excel file using linq but not specifying specific column names but could i use just columns based on their order?

```
var _excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                var _info = from x in _excelFile.Worksheet()
                            select new
                            {

                            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, you can use the `WorksheetNoHeader` method to refer to columns by their index rather than their name.

Here's an example:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var indianaCompanies = from c in excel.WorksheetNoHeader()
                       where c[2] == "IN" //value in 3rd column
                       select c;
```

Comment: So if i have 13 columns i would do c[1] .... all the way to c[13]. what does "IN" stand for? am i supposed to replaced with an item in a column?

Comment: I removed the where statement and created a foreach statement for each item in "indianaCompanies" and assigned a header based on the column: ElementAt(0)...

Comment: The code is just an example. So in this case it is filtering to only include rows whose value at the second index equals 'IN'

Comment: @Masriyah It's a 0 based index, so if you have 13 columns then it would be between c[0] and c[12]